# Creating new pdf based on mean, standard deviation and skewness

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, distribution, statsmodels

I have two time series with their mean and standard deviations and skewness computed.

How can I generate new probability density function(pdf) based on the mean and standard deviation of the first time series but skewness of the second time series.

```
  ts1 = [[ 0.24795413,  0.51981795, -1.128888  , -0.3915509 , -0.36329997,
    0.88802624,  1.1253957 ,  0.14258218, -0.55445707, -0.79443187,
   -0.16986907,  1.5396615 ,  1.7831599 ,  0.48034644, -0.55335957,
   -0.1698935 , -0.82943815, -1.2654774 , -1.0019791 ,  0.2947774 ,
   -0.38959527, -1.193097  ,  0.19199276, -0.24384224,  1.0309464 ,
   -0.54779184, -1.2194977 , -0.56049407,  0.33375692,  0.09617996,
    1.500001  ,  1.3636391 , -0.6977335 ,  1.14598   , -0.31681216,
    0.14813781,  1.2058297 , -0.5362634 , -0.18963599, -0.82915914,
   -0.46238124, -0.5534528 ,  0.2932713 ,  0.03283417, -0.59320515,
   -0.15333033,  0.418383  ,  0.623021  ,  2.9942613 ,  1.1455983 ,
   -0.7301076 ,  0.47346616,  0.96548057,  1.7798176 ,  1.4704127 ,
    0.12636256, -0.54934335, -0.057479]

   ts2 = [-0.20055497, -1.0812824 ,  1.6640332 , -0.9939632 ,  0.05211592,
    1.4842485 , -0.3094573 ,  0.35551405,  0.38313067, -1.0607151 ,
   -0.24302316, -0.97898716, -1.3700265 ,  0.5152137 , -0.49310505,
    0.71188784, -0.51848483,  0.16944373, -0.5372622 , -0.60573167,
    0.04732573,  0.34191012, -0.23362386,  1.5668747 , -0.91083133,
   -0.7176449 ,  1.4817567 , -0.2580676 ,  1.0231726 ,  0.10230541,
    0.16726625, -1.4672999 ,  0.40618753, -1.4019163 , -0.1177727 ,
   -0.21126366, -0.9413029 ,  0.3704642 ,  0.11061847,  2.4474611 ,
   -0.5796859 , -1.2674994 , -0.44353878, -1.2688683 , -0.5369506 ,
   -0.53735554,  1.7200137 ,  2.3995981 , -1.4367745 , -0.5959428 ,
    0.63681364,  1.0187957 , -0.97254455, -0.50130427, -0.31367695,
    0.43504715, -0.60908884, -1.176665]

    m1 = np.mean(ts1) std1 = np.std(ts1) skw1 = scipy.stats.skew(ts1)

   skw2 = scipy.stats.skew(ts2)



   # m1 mean of pdf1, std1 standard deviation and skw1 is skewness    
   pdf1 = m1 std1 skw1 

   # how can I get pdf 2 to be something like this

   pdf2 = m1, std1, sk2 ( here I am using different skewness but 
   same meand and standard deviation)
```

Comment: Hi @user11036847, it would be appreciate if you could provide sample data and the desired output as well.

Comment: Also please indicate what you mean by "PDF" and by "generating a PDF".

Comment: I have edited, I want to generate a new histogram or probability density function  using mean, standard deviation of series one but the skewness of series 2

Comment: Adjusting the skewness appears to be a difficult problem. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2377/53512) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/43482/53512) for related information. Why do you want to do that anyway? Both series seem to have pretty similar skewness.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ts1': ts1, 'ts2': ts2})
df.describe()
```

[image]

### Data Plot:

```
df.plot()
```

[image: data plot]

### Probability Density Function (PDF):

[pandas.DataFrame.plot.density](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.density.html) for further details

```
df.plot.density()
```

[image: pde plot]

Comment: @ Trenton_M thanks, but I want something slightly different. I want to plot a third density using the mean of ts1 but standard deviatin of ts2

Comment: Is there a way I can tweak the standard deviation of ts1 whiles keeping the mean constant?

Comment: Probably the fastest way is to add a column for each calculation and then plot it as shown above.  For example `df['ts1_mean_pdf'] = some_calculation`.  You can create whatever calculation you need and create a new column based on the calculation.